# Converting string to number not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm confused.

`$("#total-kwh-cost").text()` contains the text `$920`.  It has been previously calculated and formatted using `toLocaleString()` as `USD currency` and stored in a `div` with an `id` of `#total-kwh-cost`.

I retrieve the text from the `div` using:

```
var tkwhCostp = $("#total-kwh-cost").text().replace(/,/g,''); // returns $920 as text
```

Then I check it to make sure it's been a number

```
console.log("tkwhCostp text is: "+tkwhCostp);       // return NaN
console.log("tkwhCostp isNAN? "+isNaN(tkwhCostp));  // returns true
tkwhCostp = parseFloat(tkwhCostp);                  // Run it through parseFloat
console.log("tkwhCostp text is: "+tkwhCostp);       // returns NaN  
console.log("tkwhCostp isNAN? "+isNaN(tkwhCostp));  // returns true
```

I tried `parseInt()` and `Number()` and get the same results.  This has to be local to my code.

It also appears to only affect variables that I converted using `toLocaleString()`.

I'm at a loss as to how to convert it back to a number so I can add to the number 920.

Comment: A leading `$` is not part of any number syntax, you'll have to strip that off.

Comment: I see you're using jquery already, so why don't you use `$.data()`? Like this: `$("#total-kwh-cost").data('value', originalNumberValueNotString )` and then when you need it: `var tkwhCostp = $("#total-kwh-cost").data('value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript interprets the `$` sign as non-numeric and the entire parsing operation fails, returning `NaN` (not a number).

To remove the comma and the dollar sign:

```
var tkwhCostp = $("#total-kwh-cost").text().replace(/,/g,'').replace(/\$/g, ''); // returns 920 as text
```

Comment: Aaaah!  @Manuvo, I wasn't escaping the $.  Duh!!

Answer (score 1):

It has been previously calculated and formatted using toLocaleString() for better display in HTML which is fine. But why is it then stored in the div to be retrieved later on by JS? You already have the original, unformatted value in JS for your calculations, it's better to use that instead.

```
let originalValue = 920;
let formatedValue = originalValue.toLocaleString("en-US", {style:"currency", currency:"USD"});
$("#total-kwh-cost").text(formatedValue); // use the formatted value in HTML for display
let calculatedValue = originalvalue * 0.25; // use the original value for math calculations
```

You are getting NaN because tolocaleString() changes the value into a string that cannot be automatically converted to a Number. The parseInt() and Number() functions cannot convert anything into a number. If the first character of a string is not a digit e.g. $, then NaN (Not-a-Number) is returned.

Comment: I have removed the '$' sign from the values used to display a dollar value.
`$920` is now `920` in `var1`; `$2,600` is now `2600` in `var2`. 
When I add `var1+var2` I get `9202600` and not `3520`

Comment: Right now I have two variables that isNaN returns false, that concatenate like strings rather than sum.

Comment: They are still strings if you got them using text(), even after you remove the '$'. So you'll need to remove the '$" first, and then use parseInt() before using them for math calculations. All that work is best avoided as much as possible, by keeping your data in JS and only getting data from HTML when you really have to, e.g. from user form input.

Comment: These are in a `display:table`. There are 5 `display:table-row`, and 7 `display:table-column` per row. Row 1 are headers, row 5 hold column totals.

I display totals as decimal or currency with $ signs and commas. This data is text. 

When user inputs data for row two, I need to total row1+row2 and replace the total. I strip off the '$' and ',' from row1 totals, so they can be added to row2 data. isNaN returns false, row1 totals are now numbers. But they concatenate instead of adding.

the code:
`tkwhCost2 = $("#total-kwh-cost").text().replace(/,/g,'').replace(/\$/g,'')`

Comment: How does the user add a new row? Are you using standard form fields like <input> to collect user input data?

Comment: It's a table with 5 rows and 7 columns. Row 1 is the headers, row 5 holds the totals, and rows 2-4 is where the user can select up to 3 space types. Columns 1 and 2 are a `<select>` to pick the space type, and `<input>` to get the floor area. The 3rd column shows the percent of total floor area by space type, and columns 4-7 hold the calculated results for kwh (use & cost) and fuel (use & cost).

When the user selects row 2 `<select>` and `<input>`, I call the totals for columns 4-7, and add row 2 results to the totals and then set the totals using `.text()`.

Comment: Yes to the `using standard form fields like <input> to collect user input data` as well as <select>.

There are three static rows.  the first two columns are the <select> and <input> respectively.  

Columns 3-7 calculate based on the input from columns 1 and 2.  

Row 5 holds the totals for columns 3-7. 

I need to add the calculated results from row 2 to what's in the totals columns and then repeat the process if there is a third row. 

I have not coded an option to add a row, but I'd still have the same problem if I did.

Comment: Ok. Was just curious why you'd need to have something like this below using standard form fields...   `tkwhCost2 = $("#total-kwh-cost").text()`

Comment: I'm using it to store the totals.  For example, I'm taking the calculated kWh Usage for row 1, row 2, and row 3.   `$.data()` might solve my issue and save me from having to clean up the string.  I'm not aware of a simpler solution.

Comment: Why not store the totals in a JavaScript variable which is updated every time the user adds a value or row?

Comment: That was my first intent, and I kept losing visibility on the variables previously set.